# Passing an url to a template

Tags: mediawiki-templates

I am trying to pass a simple mwurl to a template, but this doesn't seem to work always.

Template:U:

```
my link: {{{1}}}
```

Calling code:

```
{{U|[https://www.istaria-lexica.de/index.php?title=User:Elteria_Shadowhand/sandbox&action=edit test link]}}
```

If I use google.com instead, the template works. I assume there's some problem with special characters? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the equal sign in the URL. It has a special meaning in the template parametre syntax: what is on the left of the equal sign is treated as the parametre's name, what is on the right, its value.

You can either:

- Pass the URL as a named parametre rather than an anonymous: `{{U|1=[https://www.istaria-lexica.de/index.php?title=User:Elteria_Shadowhand/sandbox&action=edit test link]}}`,
- Replace all equal signs with the pre-defined (in recent versions of *MediaWiki*) template `{{=}}`: `{{U|[https://www.istaria-lexica.de/index.php?title{{=}}User:Elteria_Shadowhand/sandbox&action{{=}}edit test link]}}`.

In addition:

- perhaps, moving the square brackets from the template parameter to its definition would be a good idea: Template:U = `my link: [{{{1}}} {{{2}}}]`,
- if the link is to the same wiki, it better to let the wiki engine form it: `{{fullurl:User:Elteria Shadowhand/sandbox|action=edit}}` or, better,  `{{localurl:User:Elteria Shadowhand/sandbox|action=edit}}`. The boilerplate code can be moved to the template definition as well: Template:U = `[{{localurl:{{{1}}}|action=edit}} {{{2}}}]`, called with `{{U|User:Elteria Shadowhand/sandbox|test link}}`,
- if the link is on the same page that is to be edited, you can use `{{FULLPAGENAME}}`: Template:U = `[{{localurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}|action=edit}} {{{1}}}]`, called as `{{U|test link}}`,
- finally, if the link text is always the same, or is the linked page name, there would be no need to pass it to the template: Template:U = `[{{localurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}|action=edit}} test link]`, called as `{{U}}`, or Template:U = `[{{localurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}|action=edit}} {{FULLPAGENAME}}]`, also called as `{{U}}`, or Template:U = `[{{localurl:{{{1}}}|action=edit}} {{{1}}}]`, called as `{{U|User:Elteria Shadowhand/sandbox}}`.

Comment: Thank you, Alexander, for you thorough explanation. That helped me massively to understand löinking better.